# Invalid Android taken photo size

Tags: android, camera

I cannot figure out why when I capture the photo using Android camera API, the taken photo doesn't match the preview.

For a preview I use a FrameLayout which size is 817 x 770 pixels.
For front facing camera I have chosen preview size of 1280 x 768 pixels.
As I would like to have a camera preview that covers the whole preview area, I setup a FrameLayout with a size 1283 x 770 pixels (keeping the aspect ratio of the supported preview frame) that is centered to its parent (817 x 770 FrameLayout):

```
D/TEST    (29556): View hierarchy (x/y/w/h):
D/TEST    (29556):  1050/168/817/770    android.widget.FrameLayout (the parent)
D/TEST    (29556):      0/0/1283/770    android.widget.FrameLayout
D/TEST    (29556):          0/0/-1/-1   com.example.cameratest.MainActivity$CameraPreview
```

So I would expect that the preview is a little bit cut off but for sure centered.
And it is not. When I take the photo I can clearly see that the what is in the preview middle is a not in the middle of the taken photo: [original-full-size.bmp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs6bxxfz9qemz6b/original-full-size.bmp?dl=0)

For this example, the ends of the pen were positioned in the top-left and bottom-right corners of the preview area. And in the picture taken they are not. There is a huge left margin + a smaller on to the right.

The code that I used to reproduce the behaviour (an extract from larger piece with some hardcoded values) can be found here: [CameraTest.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8bxavoxvu9dp4a/CameraTest.zip?dl=0).

The problem is I cannot assume the preview area matches the ratio of supported camera preview size and I don't want to have blank areas. I opt for loosing a piece of preview area. The user doesn't care that 30px were lost on both sides :) But I cannot find the reason why the preview is so strangely positioned inside the whole picture.

The code was run on Nexus 7 (2013).

My activity layout is like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="817px"
        android:layout_height="770px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1050px"
        android:layout_marginTop="168px"
        android:background="#770000" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now in order to maintain the aspect ratio I add another FrameLayout (the second one from view hierarchy dump, 1283 x 770 pixels). And CameraPreview is a simple SurfaceView

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
FrameLayout previewHolder = new FrameLayout(this);
previewHolder.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView);
rootView.addView(previewHolder);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsRoot = rootView.getLayoutParams();
Log.d("TEST", "Root: " + paramsRoot.width + " x " + paramsRoot.height);
Log.d("TEST", "Preview: " + width + " x " + height);

previewHolder.addView(cameraPreview);
```

The problem appears if the previewHolder bounds are out of the screen bounds. If I move the preview area more to the left, so that the left margin and right margin is more than or equal to (1283 - 817) / 2 then it looks fine.

Comment: How do you setup your layout? You can try negative margins.

Comment: With negative margins (instead of gravity) it is the same.

Comment: I would suggest to try (depricated) AbsoluteLayout in this case. I succeeded this way to force "cropped" camera view when I really needed this, but this was with OS build 2.3 (not even 2.3.3), on a Samsung Galaxy S device. Such setups are very device- and build- specific. The more universal approach would be to use TextureSurface (API level 11): the OpenGL setup with any margins and stretching uses only documented features.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with this TextureSurface as I'm targeting API Level 16